# Why does nCurses (C++) block System() function?

Tags: c++, system, ncurses

I don't know if it is a thing just for me but I need to open a file with notepad on windows in a C++ program. I use at the same time ncurses for the pseudo-GUI but I noticed that all the "system()" calls don't work at all

```
void test() {

    cout<<"\n\nTEST FUNCTION\n";
    system("file.xml");

}
```

**does** open the file but if I use

```
void test() {

    cout<<"\n\nTEST FUNCTION\n";
    initscr();
    system("file.xml");
    endwin();

}
```

It doesn't work. With Windows' GetLastError() it gives me error 87 (invalid parameter) but for opening a file the command used is just the file name itself

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your `system` command is likely trying to execute the command `file.xml`. Did you try `system("notepad.exe file.xml")`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it doesn't work and I don't know why, on MacOS if I change it with system("open file.xml"); in a ncurses screen it works

Comment: Error 87 means _The parameter is incorrect_. Have you copied the code _exactly_ as it is into the question?

Comment: What do you expect `system("file.xml")` to do?  Please read the documentation for [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did, It wouldn't have worked without nCurses if I did it wrong at the start

Comment: @G.M. It just need to run the command "file.xml" in the shell, on windows if you call a file name it just opens it on the default program that you use to open that kind of file, but my question is just why it just runs good if ncurses isn't used but if I use it it doesn't run anything, it seems like it literally skips the instruction

Comment: Have you also tried `errno = 0; std::cout << system("notepad.exe file.xml") << '\n' << std::perror("system") << '\n';`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it gives me this:
-1073741502                     system: No error

Comment: In an ordinary C++ program you might've noticed that if you use `std::getline` and, when prompted for input, typed "foo", changed your mind, backspaced, then typed "bar", then your program ends up being completely unaware of what you initially typed. You might've also noticed that a curses program is painfully aware of ***every*** keystroke when it happens. If you ponder on both facts, for a minute or two, the answer to your question should be obvious.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so the problem is that ncurses “overrides” the shell and it doesn’t allow system() to be executed? Or am I wrong? (If I’m wrong can you explain better so I can understand better)

Comment: `ncurses` puts the terminal into a state that normally a program started from the shell does not expect to deal with. The results are unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

ncurses on Windows could refer to different environments:

- Cygwin (where opening an xml file probably does not work, since `system` uses `sh` rather than `cmd`)
- MinGW (which would use `cmd`)
- WSL (undocumented like most of WSL, but probably like Cygwin)

With MinGW, ncurses switches the console mode by creating a [screen buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers) (analogous to xterm's alternate screen), which allows it to address cells on the visible screen.  Doing that entails changing the [inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-input-buffer) for that window.  `cmd` would in that case change its behavior regarding [file associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc).

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot, to fix my problem on windows I just use WinExec() and with MacOS and Linux I use the normal System() because I noticed that this problem occurs only on Windows